# error con "self" en python

Tags: python

**estoy tratando de realizar una tarea que incluya los siguientes pasos**:

#2. Crear una clase Robot

#2.1 Agregar constructor, atributos (5)

#2.2 Agregar métodos (3)

#2.3 Agregar Setters

#2.4 Permitir que el robot pierda batería por cada kilómetro recorrido.

#2.5 Permitir que el robot dispare y se quede sin balas.

#2.6 Si el robot está por debajo de las 5 balas o debajo del 10% de pila, entrar en modo ahorro

**pero al iniciar el código me da un error porque faltan argumentos en la clase "self" pero no puedo detectar qué me falta, ¿alguien podría ayudarme?**

**(el error que obtengo es que cuando quiero realizar la función de recorrer, la función debería quitar 5 de batería e imprimir "El robot recorrió un kilómetro" y luego seguir ejecutando las otras funciones.)**

```
class Robot:
    #2.1 Constructor
    def init (self):
        self.nombre=None
        self.bateria=100
        self.color=None
        self.balas=34
        self.brazos=0
    #2.2 Métodos
    def recorrer(self):
        self.bateria-=5
        print('El robot recorrió un kilómetro; su bateria ahora es de ',self.bateria,'%')
        self.bateria<=4 or self.balas<=9
        print('Ahorro de energía activado.')
    def desparar(self):
        self.balas-=1
        print('El robot desparó, ahora tiene', self.balas, 'balas')
    #2.3 Setters
    def cambiar_nombre(self, nom):
        self.nombre=nom
        print('El robot se llama', nom)
    def cambiar_brazos(self, num):
        self.brazos=num
        print('El robot tiene', num, 'brazos')
    def cambiar_bateria(self, bateria):
        self.bateria=bateria
        print('Su bateria ahora es de', self.bateria, '%')
robot_7=Robot
robot_7.recorrer()
robot_7.cambiar_nombre('Alex')
```

**me sale este error, pero no se como solucionarlo:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
line 36, in <module>
robot_7.recorrer()
TypeError: Robot.recorrer() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El primer error es:

```
robot_7=Robot
```

Esto deja la variable `robot_7` apuntando a la **clase** Robot; no a un objeto de la clase.

Lo que necesitas es *instanciar* (crear) un objeto de la clase. Para eso pones los paréntesis:

```
robot_7=Robot()
```

Segundo, el método `__init__()` lleva unos doble underscore por ambos lados.

Corrige en

```
class Robot:
    #2.1 Constructor
    def __init__ (self):
```

#### Demo

```
class Robot:
    #2.1 Constructor
    def __init__ (self):
        self.nombre=None
        self.bateria=100
        self.color=None
        self.balas=34
        self.brazos=0
    #2.2 Métodos
    def recorrer(self):
        self.bateria-=5
        print('El robot recorrió un kilómetro; su bateria ahora es de ',self.bateria,'%')
        self.bateria<=4 or self.balas<=9
        print('Ahorro de energía activado.')
    def desparar(self):
        self.balas-=1
        print('El robot desparó, ahora tiene', self.balas, 'balas')
    #2.3 Setters
    def cambiar_nombre(self, nom):
        self.nombre=nom
        print('El robot se llama', nom)
    def cambiar_brazos(self, num):
        self.brazos=num
        print('El robot tiene', num, 'brazos')
    def cambiar_bateria(self, bateria):
        self.bateria=bateria
        print('Su bateria ahora es de', self.bateria, '%')
robot_7=Robot()
robot_7.recorrer()
robot_7.cambiar_nombre('Alex')
```

produce:

```
El robot recorrió un kilómetro; su bateria ahora es de  95 %
Ahorro de energía activado.
El robot se llama Alex

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, ahora funciona correctamente